# Terraform enclosing issue in variable assignment

Tags: terraform

I Got a syntax problem with terraform:

Let me write some pseudo code to descript the problem as the line is a bit complicated:

I would like to have **display_name** equal to **force_name** when defined.

And if not defined I would like to have name_prefix**-01**

Now the **-XX** suffix is always added in both case, and I can't enclose it correctly to add it in the else clause.

**What I tried:**
I've tried many enclosing {} "" () in differents places.

```
resource "exoscale_compute" "generic" {                      
  count = "${var.replicas}"                                  

  affinity_groups = "${var.affinity_group}"                  
  disk_size = "${var.disk_size}"                             
  display_name = "${var.force_name != "" ? var.force_name : var.name_prefix}-${format("%02d", count.index + var.replicas_index_start) }
```

**The issue:**

The output is always forcedname**-01** or nameprefix**-01**

What I'd like would be:

forcedname or nameprefix-01

Could you help ?
Thanks

Comment: fyi on the voting thing, I'm not sure you can until you have 15 reputation.  In the meantime, you can always click the tick next to my answer (or wait to see if any even more useful ones turn up first!)

Comment: Ok that's a new company profile, I've other profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the interpolation, so the 2nd option for the ?: operator becomes another string with more interpolation:

```
display_name = "${var.force_name != "" ? var.force_name : "${var.name_prefix}-${format("%02d", count.index + var.replicas_index_start)}" }
```